# usage of "so" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

> The entire motivation for networking was ***so*** people could sit at their
> dumb terminals and, instead of accessing only their local mainframes,
> access totally different mainframes.

My understanding:

1. The entire motivation for networking was <s>***so***</s> (like this), people could sit at their....
2. The entire motivation for networking was ***so people could sit at their....*** (a noun clause started by **so**)
3. The entire motivation for networking was <s>***so***</s> (that) people could sit at their....

Which one is right or none is? I'm totally confused.

**EDIT:**

Just in case if anyone else has the same question, please refer to [this](https://qr.ae/pGT0Zk) answer and thanks to @rjpond for helping me find the exact question itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between #2 and #3.  Can you explain it in different words?

Comment: @stangdon To my foreign mind, in #2 the word **so** is something like a relational pronouns (pronoun + conjunction) while in #3 **so** is function as a pure conjunction :)

Comment: (3) is overwehlmingly likely to be the intent; (1) is theoretically possible, just highly unlikely (we'd probably say "like this", "in this way", "in doing so", "by doing so" instead).

Comment: @rjpond I've edited the examples, the word "so" in #1 and #3 should have been replaced by words in brackets, not been appended.

Comment: @rjpond If #3 is the correct understanding, **so** would be a subordinating conjunction. I've been taught that **so** is a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: @preachers My understanding of "so" here is = so that (= in order that).  Now, in some cases "so" is a coordinating conjunction.  But "so (that)" is subordinating.

Comment: blah blah blah so x can y is typical in English.